# Sending a request Nusoap on php 5.6 (Working Code SOAPUI) i want the same code working from php file

Tags: php, xml, request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mun="http://www.XXXXX.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mun:MethodName>4
         <mun:xmlFile>&lt;NewDataSet&gt;
                &lt;Table&gt;                       
            &lt;/NewDataSet&gt;</mun:xmlFile>
      </mun:MethodName>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**This code works on SoapUI i need this code working on php file**

Answer (score 0):

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mun="http://www.XXXXX.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mun:MethodName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mun:xmlFile>&lt;NewDataSet&gt;
                &lt;Table&gt;
                        &lt;cod_suc&gt;14&lt;/cod_suc&gt;
                        &lt;fec_emision&gt;03/02/2020&lt;/fec_emision&gt;
                        &lt;cod_grupo_endo&gt;1&lt;/cod_grupo_endo&gt;
                        &lt;fec_vig_desde&gt;04/02/2020&lt;/fec_vig_desde&gt;
                        &lt;fec_vig_hasta&gt;03/02/2021&lt;/fec_vig_hasta&gt;
                        &lt;txt_apellido1&gt;PEREZ&lt;/txt_apellido1&gt;
                        &lt;txt_apellido2&gt;&lt;/txt_apellido2&gt;
                        &lt;txt_nombre&gt;PEPITO&lt;/txt_nombre&gt;
                        &lt;cod_tipo_persona&gt;F&lt;/cod_tipo_persona&gt;
                        &lt;cod_tipo_doc&gt;1&lt;/cod_tipo_doc&gt;
                        &lt;nro_doc&gt;123456789&lt;/nro_doc&gt;
                        &lt;cod_tipo_dir&gt;1&lt;/cod_tipo_dir&gt;
                        &lt;txt_direccion&gt;calle 45 # 45 - 16 int 1 apto 904&lt;/txt_direccion&gt;
                        &lt;cod_dpto&gt;11&lt;/cod_dpto&gt;
                        &lt;cod_municipio&gt;11001&lt;/cod_municipio&gt;
                        &lt;txt_sexo&gt;M&lt;/txt_sexo&gt;
                        &lt;cod_tipo_telef&gt;8&lt;/cod_tipo_telef&gt;
                        &lt;txt_telefono&gt;3154270&lt;/txt_telefono&gt;
                        &lt;imp_prima_total&gt;763200&lt;/imp_prima_total&gt;
                        &lt;imp_gtos_emi&gt;0&lt;/imp_gtos_emi&gt;
                        &lt;imp_iva&gt;0&lt;/imp_iva&gt;
                        &lt;cod_usuario_solicitud&gt;XXXXX&lt;/cod_usuario_solicitud&gt;
                        &lt;cod_marca_min_trans&gt;TO&lt;/cod_marca_min_trans&gt;
                        &lt;cod_modelo_min_trans&gt;999&lt;/cod_modelo_min_trans&gt;
                        &lt;cod_tipo_veh_min_trans&gt;1&lt;/cod_tipo_veh_min_trans&gt;
                        &lt;aaaa_modelo&gt;2019&lt;/aaaa_modelo&gt;
                        &lt;txt_patente&gt;GCY070&lt;/txt_patente&gt;                            
                        &lt;txt_motor&gt;1KD2842512&lt;/txt_motor&gt;
                        &lt;txt_chasis&gt;JTEBH3FJ3KK210999&lt;/txt_chasis&gt;
                        &lt;cod_destino&gt;1&lt;/cod_destino&gt;
                        &lt;cnt_toneladas&gt;0.00&lt;/cnt_toneladas&gt;
                        &lt;cnt_ocupantes&gt;7&lt;/cnt_ocupantes&gt;
                        &lt;cnt_cc&gt;2982&lt;/cnt_cc&gt;
                        &lt;cod_pais_matricula&gt;1&lt;/cod_pais_matricula&gt;
                        &lt;cod_clase_soat&gt;6&lt;/cod_clase_soat&gt;
                        &lt;nro_asociado&gt;621&lt;/nro_asociado&gt;
                        &lt;nro_formulario&gt;77504401&lt;/nro_formulario&gt;
                        &lt;nro_digito_chequeo&gt;0&lt;/nro_digito_chequeo&gt;
                        &lt;cod_motivo&gt;&lt;/cod_motivo&gt;
                        &lt;txt_marca&gt;TOYOTA&lt;/txt_marca&gt;
                        &lt;txt_modelo&gt;PRADO&lt;/txt_modelo&gt;
                        &lt;cod_valor&gt;1&lt;/cod_valor&gt;
                        &lt;imp_pagado&gt;764900&lt;/imp_pagado&gt;
                        &lt;fec_mov&gt;03/02/2020&lt;/fec_mov&gt;
                        &lt;nro_cheque&gt;&lt;/nro_cheque&gt;
                        &lt;cod_banco_emi&gt;&lt;/cod_banco_emi&gt;
                        &lt;cod_conducto&gt;&lt;/cod_conducto&gt;
                        &lt;nro_tarjeta&gt;&lt;/nro_tarjeta&gt;
                        &lt;nro_aut_tarjeta&gt;&lt;/nro_aut_tarjeta&gt;
                        &lt;nro_voucher_tarjeta&gt;&lt;/nro_voucher_tarjeta&gt;
                        &lt;nro_consec_pago&gt;1&lt;/nro_consec_pago&gt;
                        &lt;cod_tipo_agente&gt;4&lt;/cod_tipo_agente&gt;
                        &lt;cod_agente&gt;80000034&lt;/cod_agente&gt;
                        &lt;cod_pto_vta&gt;97101&lt;/cod_pto_vta&gt;
                        &lt;imp_tasa_runt&gt;1700&lt;/imp_tasa_runt&gt;
                        &lt;txt_correo&gt;v@gmail.com&lt;/txt_correo&gt;
                        &lt;txt_vin&gt;JTEBH3FJ3KK210999&lt;/txt_vin&gt;
                        &lt;cotizador/&gt;
                &lt;/Table&gt;
            &lt;/NewDataSet&gt;</mun:xmlFile>
      </mun:MethodName>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```